# KML overlay splash screen

Tags: kml, google-earth

Is there a way to get an overlay of some kind to open in GE when the user loads my kml?
I want to add a splash screen with a disclaimer on it and i want to be sure each user sees it. 
The overlay would appear as the kml is opened in GE and they would click to dismiss it.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CDATA for the description of the top-level object in your KML file (eg Doc or Folder). This will pop up as a balloon when user adds KML file to Google Earth.

If you're working with NetworkLinks, you could add the overlay when the NetworkLink first loads, then set refresh to occur a short time later (eg 5 seconds) which returns an Update with a  to remove the Overlay.